# Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function

Tags: php, function, email, message

I've tried the solutions in every related/similar posts but no luck. My client is getting restless. This code worked fine for months. Ive tried using the STMP that you see commented out, but then I get a connection error. Its a linux server with the most recent PHPMailer installed.

```
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->IsMAIL();
 //$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
 date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
 //$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers  
 //$mail->Port = 587; // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
 //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
 //$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
 //$mail->Username = "test@gmail.com";                 // SMTP username
 //$mail->Password = "password";                           // SMTP password

 $address = "test@gmail.com";
 $mail->From = "test@gmail.com";
 //$mail->FromName = 'FleetwayCapital.com'; 
 //$mail->addAddress('credit.fcc@fleetwaycapital.com', 'Fleetway Capital');     // Add a        recipient
 $mail->AddAddress($address);
 //$mail->addAddress('test@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
 $mail->addReplyTo("test@gmail.com");
 //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com'); 
 //$mail->addBCC('test@gmail.com');

 $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
 //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
 //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
 $mail->isHTML(true);                               // Set email format to HTML
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
 $mail->Subject = 'Credit Application Submission';
 $mail->Body    = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />  
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  body,td,th {
   color: #000; 
  }

  .text {
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   margin:auto;
  width:500px;
   font-size:15px;

   }
   </style>
   </head>

   <body>
   <div class="em"><div class="text"><br /><br />
    A client has submitted a credit application.<br /><br /> 



    Have a lovely day!<br />

    End of message
    </div>
    </div>
    </body> 
    </html>'
    ;

    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
     echo 'Message could not be sent.';
     echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     } else {
     echo 'Message has been sent'; 
     }
```

Im not really sure what should be in the php.ini file, or how to tell if sendmail is installed. Like I said, it worked fine for months, and I never had this issue on other servers I have PHPmailer installed Any help would be great.

Comment: I've seen this once when *mail* function disabled. Can you verify if [function_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) ?

Comment: I just tried a very simple PHPMailer Demo and i am getting the same error.  Soo its not my code?

Comment: Code is too minimal to produce any error anyway. I suggest to get in touch with your Host, since they're offering PHPMailer. The error is too generic. As i said, i've seen it when _mail_ function was disabled but also where email _subject_ was too long and one time i've seen it in some host's Cpanel, on PHPMailer config there (there was a from e-mail address used there). Get in touch with them.